# JavaScript: Function to compare json data trends

Tags: javascript, json

**Objective** is to loop through JSON data file to compare the trends. If the previous value of the data is less or greater than the current value, it should change the image ID'ed Snow1_img

**Condition** There exists about 8 different values / variables that I need to perform the above object, so, I thought one way will be to write a separate function that takes in arguments of ElementID and trendDirection

To keep it simple for now, I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ohak2Lr4/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="Dboxes">
  <div class="TableContainer">
    <div class="Value">
      <img id="Snow1_img" class="MainImg" src="img/grnsqr.png" /> <span id="Snow1" class="metrics">##</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Value
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.MainImg
{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.TableContainer
{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  height: 25px;
}
.Dboxes {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px; 
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var counter = 0; // Trial 

$(document).ready(function () {       

  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

       myJson();

    });

function myJson() {

    $.getJSON('JsonData.json', function (response) {

        var looping = setInterval(function () {
        var TrialCount = response.length;
            var Info = response[counter];
            var Snow1_Data = Info.Snow1;

            document.getElementById("Snow1").innerHTML = Snow1_Data

            counter++;
            if (counter == TrialCount) clearInterval(looping);

        }, 100);
    });
};
```

Currently, it is taking the external data from JSON file  named JsonData.json, looping through each data values and updating it to the **id="Snow1"**. What I want to do is, if the previous looped data for Snow1 is less or greater than the current value, the **id="Snow1_img** image should change. This same function will be applied to Sun1, Moon1, etc. (8 variables total).

How can I write a function that takes in data IDs from these variables and perform this task?

I am very new to the coding / JavaScript so please bear with me. From my theory, I feel the steps I need are: Declaring new function to take in elementID and trendDirection such as

```
function UpdateTrendIcon(elementID, trendDirection){ 
    $(elementID).getAttribute(trendDirection);
}
```

and declaring a previousArray = []; and currentArray = []; and have a if statement that compares these two array..... again, my theory may be wrong.

Please let me know of a way to do this and give me an example if possible.

the Json file can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8pergj6x9ktarg/JsonData.json?dl=0

Clarifying the comment below: The image - img id="Snow1_img" is suppose to change depending on the current value. If the current value is greater than previous, it should change to image 2, if it is lesser than previous, it should change to image 1. **It should animate the changes/trend over a given time period**

Comment: Not sure I get what you're hoping to see in the end. A single image state that represents a trend? Or a series of images that display a trend? Or...?

Comment: @Will My apology. The image - img id="Snow1_img" is suppose to change depending on the current value. If the current value is greater than previous, it should change to image 2, if it is lesser than previous, it should change to image 1

Comment: But, as described (or as I understand what you're describing) with say 30 values in the JSON for "snow1", the image will only display the relationship between the final two values of snow.

Comment: @Will That is correct, the image should change constantly, every time the loop goes to the next value of data. Let's say x1:2,  x2:4, x3:2, x4:8....  then it will change to image 2, image 1, image 2.
If there are let's say 50 data values, the image will change 49 times if there are difference in the values

Comment: ah, so you want it to animate the changes/trend over a given time period? If so, consider adding that to your original question.

Comment: @Will That is exactly it. Sorry, I was not sure how to ask that question because I didn't know what to ask.